# How to remove the lowercase characters from a textbox retaining only the uppercase?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove lowercase on a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093330/how-to-remove-lowercase-on-a-textbox)

I'm trying to remove the lower case letters on a TextBox..

For example, short alpha code representing the course(e.g., 'BSCS' for 'Bacheclor of Science in Computer Science):

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093330/how-to-remove-lowercase-on-a-textbox

Comment: Wow this is copied word for word ;p

Comment: @Marlon he changed the inner quotes... this must be homework. Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

texbox.Text = Regex.Replace(textbox.Text, "[^A-Z]", "");
```

Anything you don't want (non-uppercase characters) will be replaced with blank.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Char.IsUpper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s91f3by.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual c# code but I can conceptualize it for you if you're SURE that all acronyms will be properly represented by just the capitals in the given string.

- blow the string up into an array where each array element is a character
- convert each element to it's character representation
- check it against the numeric order of available capital letters

  - if it's a capital letter, add it to a variable for use later

Pseudo-code:

```
$charArray = $string.split("")
foreach ($item in $charArray) {
   if ([int]$item > 64 && [int]$item < 91) {
      $acronym += [char]$item
   }
}
```

Edit:  Here is the character reference chart:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60ecse8t(VS.80).aspx